# What's the title of the background music played when The Doctor flies Earth back home?

Tags: doctor-who, music-identification

In the *Journey's End*, when The Doctor flies Earth back home, a background music is played which is my favorite.

I just wanted to listen it on Spotify, but didn't know what to search. Finally, I found it on YouTube by searching "Doctor flies Earth home", but I still don't have its title.

(music starts at 0:25)

I know that it is composed by Murray Gold (I saw him playing it in BBC concert).

Can you please identify its title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [official soundtrack album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who:_Series_4_(soundtrack)) identifies it as the "*Song of Freedom*". You can hear an extended version below.

---

It might interest you to learn that the song contains [lyrics](https://web.archive.org/web/20130819021537/http://feelgoodsongs.info/song/song-of-freedom) in chanted latin;

*Cum tacent clament

Cum tacent clament.
Serva ne

Servan tuter

Sevan servan tuter

Dum inter homines sumus colamus humanitatem

Cum tacent clament

Dum inter homines sumus colamus humanitatem

Cum tacent clament.*

Which translates into English as;

*With silence, we shout

With silence, we shout

Without salvation

He provides our salvation

He provides us our salvation

As long as we are among humans, let us be humane

With silence, we shout

As long as we are among humans, let us be humane

With silence, we shout.*

Comment: It's originally from "Planet of the Ood", isn't it?

Comment: @AndreKR I don't think so.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation Ok, only [the lyrics are](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Songs_of_Freedom_and_Captivity), the music is [quite different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXEdzgMvzcA).

Answer (score 7):

The clip (2 minutes 51 seconds) is Song of Freedom, credited to Murray Gold.
It's documented in the IMDB.com notes on that episode, and the purchase-able copy
was available https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who:_Series_4_(soundtrack).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; just because it's not as good as the top answer doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: @Quesnel - because it was posted ten minutes after mine and contains no new information, I expect.